# differences between rdbms vs. spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, rdbms, query-performance, apache-spark-sql

I'm working with Apache-Spark and in my project, I want to use Spark-SQL. But, I have to be sure Spark-SQL's query performance. I know that Spark-SQL is not effective like RDBMS. But I want to learn that are there too much time gap between Spark-SQL and RDBMS queries?

For example, I'm working on Virtual Machine which has 4 gb ram and 1 core CPU. It is a slow system. I have a small data set with 2 tables. First one has 5M records, second one has 1K records. When I join two tables, query takes about 60 seconds. Is it normal for Spark-SQL with this hardware? If I do same join operation with RDBMS, it takes too less time but I can't test it with physical limits at office.

And a last question: How can I reduce query time in Spark-SQL?

Comment: Can i ask you why you want to use spark while you have one machine and only small data sizes ??

Comment: @Abdulrahman, we will use clusters and streaming operations with large data sets later. But, I'm now researching how we apply Spark and Spark SQL for our application. This machine and small sets are for researching.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is the virtual machine. I was on the same boat, and what ended up doing it was installing Spark on Windows (you can do that, just google it). The performance was much better (I have a 4 core laptop, 4gb ram and ssd drive).

Spark-SQL is really powerful, depending on your needs. What you are comparing with the performance will be amazing, but you need to do/implement things differently than what you were used to doing in a regular RDBMS.